# Javascript/Jquery Convert string to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a string

```
var traingIds = "${triningIdArray}";  // ${triningIdArray} this value getting from server 
alert(traingIds)  // alerts [1,2]
var type = typeof(traingIds ) 
alert(type)   // // alerts String
```

now i want to convert this to array so that i can iterate

i tried

```
var trainindIdArray = traingIds.split(',');
$.each(trainindIdArray, function(index, value) { 
    alert(index + ': ' + value);   // alerts 0:[1 ,  and  1:2]
});
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Since array literal notation is still valid JSON, you can [use `JSON.parse()`](http://jsfiddle.net/3S6C8/) to convert that string into an array, and from there, use it's values.

```
var test = "[1,2]";
parsedTest = JSON.parse(test); //an array [1,2]

//access like and array
console.log(parsedTest[0]); //1
console.log(parsedTest[1]); //2
```

Comment: Wow, this is just brilliant... and simple  Thank you.

Comment: I have input just like OPs, except the var is set to the .attr() of my element. It has `typeof string` and looks like `"['foo','bar']"`. When I try JSON.parse i get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` error.  Any idea?

Answer (score 14):

Change

`var trainindIdArray = traingIds.split(',');`

to

`var trainindIdArray = traingIds.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(',');`

That will basically remove `[` and `]` and then split the string

Answer (score 11):

Assuming, as seems to be the case, `${triningIdArray}` is a server-side placeholder that is replaced with JS array-literal syntax, just lose the quotes. So:

```
var traingIds = ${triningIdArray};
```

not

```
var traingIds = "${triningIdArray}";
```

Answer (score 5):

check this out :)

```
var traingIds = "[1,2]";  // ${triningIdArray} this value getting from server 
alert(traingIds);  // alerts [1,2]
var type = typeof(traingIds);
alert(type);   // // alerts String

//remove square brackets
traingIds = traingIds.replace('[','');
traingIds = traingIds.replace(']','');
alert(traingIds);  // alerts 1,2        
var trainindIdArray = traingIds.split(',');

​for(i = 0; i< trainindIdArray.length; i++){
    alert(trainindIdArray[i]); //outputs individual numbers in array
    }​
```

Comment: You can use eval. eg. eval("[1,2]") # => [1,2]

Comment: It surprises me @Sam Kah Chiin 's comment is not an answer. It really a great deal to this question. it is single lined and simple. Thanks

Comment: @YoungMillie, actually using `eval` in javascript can be dangerous as improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks. Check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) :)

Comment: Thanks @Sam Kah Chiin , knowledge is power. I now understand what eval is and how dangerous it can be.

Comment: Then in that case...I guess @Clayton 's answer is also a good way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways to convert a `string` into an `array` in `JavaScript`.
Here you have code examples on how they look.

**Example Code:**

```js
let string = "Javascript";
```

**First Method:**

```
let array = [string];
```

**Second Method:**

```
let array = [...string];
```

**Third Method:**

```
let array = Array.from(string);
```

**Fourth Method:**

```
let array = string.split('');
```

I hope that my answer helps you!