# Pop array element, split it and save it into different array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to pop array element, split it and save into different array.
say I have two array

```
arr1 = ["a:b", "c:d"]
arr2 = []
```

I want to have arr2 as

```
arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I tried

```
var arr1 = ["a:b", "c:d"]

var arr2 = [];

        var tempdata;

        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            tempdata = arr1.pop();

            arr2.merge(tempdata.split(':'));
        }
```

but firebug gives me an error saying merge is not a function.

I also tried

```
var arr1 = ["a:b", "c:d"]

var arr2 = [];

        var tempdata;


        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            tempdata = arr1.pop();
            var temparray = [];
            temparray = tempdata.split(':'); 
            arr2.merge(temparray);
        }
```

still no luck.

Thanks for the help.
PS:I don't mind using Jquery.

Comment: use push instead of merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr2 = $.map(arr1, function(elem) {
    return elem.split(':');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FC5tL/

Comment: Thanks, That worked. nice and concise. but SO wants me to wait for 5 mins before i mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the first array to string then convert it back to array just like this

```
var trainindIdArray = traingIds.split(',');
$.each(trainindIdArray, function(index, value) { 
    alert(index + ': ' + value);   // alerts 0:[1 ,  and  1:2]
});
```

from [Javascript/Jquery Convert string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776204/javascript-jquery-convert-string-to-array)
question...

happy coding..:D

Answer (score 0):

on each iteration:

```
arr2 = arr2.concat(tempdata.split(':'))
```